# Including expect/tcl library for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, tcl, expect, include-path

Recently I found an [example](http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/code-blogs/1358/using-expect-script-cc-library-to-manage-linux-hosts) of how to use the expect library in C++. I tried to compile it, but the compiler (g++) said, that tcl8.5/expect.h doesn't exists. So I tried to include tcl8.6/expect.h - still the same error. I checked the /usr/include/ directory and I wasn't surprised when I've noticed, that there is no tcl8.x directory.
I've searched for files with "expect" in their name. Here's what I found:

```
/usr/include/expect_tcl.h
/usr/include/expect_comm.h
/usr/include/expect.h
```

Unfortunately when I tried to include any of these I got the following list of errors during compilation:

```
> g++ test.cpp -Wall -std=c++0x -ltcl8.6 -lglog -o test
  /tmp/cce8k1BA.o: In function `task(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&)':
  test.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `exp_is_debugging'
  test.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `exp_timeout'
  test.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `exp_popen'
  etc...
```

How can I solve this problem?

**[EDIT]**
When I tried to link it with the expect lib (-lexpect) I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpect
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm sure that both - tcl8.6 and expect 5.45-4 are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of distributing Expect these days puts the shared library in a non-standard location and `load`s it dynamically by full pathname. This works well and is minimal fuss for most people, but does make it rather hard to use Expect's C interface in your own code.

The easiest way is going to be to build your own copy from source, especially as that will give you control over how exactly it was built. This can particularly include keeping the majority of symbols in the library instead of stripping them on install, which will help a lot with debugging. You probably ought to use the [current supported version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/files/Expect/5.45/). (Yes, it's a release from several years ago. It doesn't need a lot of support effort most of the time.)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't linked to the `expect` library during your build. Add `-lexpect` to your `g++` command.

Comment: Actually I tried to link it but I got the following error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpect

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Linux build chains, but I would assume you either haven't installed the library properly or your linker doesn't know where to look for it. Did you install `expect-dev`? Can you search your drive for the library and see where it is and find out why your linker can't find it?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no package called expect-dev for my distribution (Arch Linux). And as I said before, I've already searched for this library. The only files I've found are listed in the question above.

Comment: If there's no prebuilt library then you'll have to build it yourself. It looks like http://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/files/ has the source files.